# how to remove pop-out and zoom button google doc?

Tags: pdf, iframe, google-api, android-webview

I am loading the pdf documents in WebView through appending the pdf url to google doc api

http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=myurl

Pdf is loading just fine but the webpage displays two options - Zoom-in and Pop-Out. Is there any way to disable/hide pop-out option and zoom button? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use it and its working fine for pop out click disabled.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-GSQQnc-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Better and easy way just open your google doc file link.
Right click on zoom button and select inspect element and copy the parent `div` class name.
Then add it like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.querySelector('[class=\"ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b\"]').remove();})()");
```

inside onPageFinished() method.